# Can we Set Alert Rule With Variable in Description?

Tags: azure, azure-alerts, azure-metrics-advisor

In Azure Metric Alert rule. For example If i have 3 dimension with name "vm1", "vm2", "vm3" and condition is if cpu over 80% then trigger alert to pagerduty. If one of that have cpu over 80% then trigger to pagerduty with description or name is "Alert CPU Over 80% in {VMNAME in Dimension}. like this.

Have example or any way for config it.?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Metric Alert rule. For example If i have 3 dimension with name "vm1", "vm2", "vm3" and condition is if `CPU` over 80% then trigger alert to pagerduty.

Note: `Azure Monitor Metric Alerts` do not support dynamic variables in the alert description field to trigger alerts for individual `Virtual Machine` names.

You can create separate metric alert rules for each `VM` dimension with a static description.

> Ex: Alert Rule for "vm1" with description "Alert CPU Over 80% in vm1"

I have created an alert rule for when the `CPU` load reaches `80%` on a `Virtual Machine`.

[image]

Alert triggered when `CPU` load reached **80%** in the portal as below.

[image]

Alert received to registered email as below.

[image]

You can similarly create multiple alerts for other virtual machines and apply an existing `Action Group`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. It's support alert for dimension in APIM each API Alert with variable name ?

Comment: Azure API Management allows you to set up alerts based on various metrics and conditions, including those related to APIs and dimensions. You can create alerts for specific metrics like request count, response time, or any other custom metric you have defined. You can also specify dimensions to narrow down the scope of the alert.